# How to mask a signal when I handle a variable in signal _handler and in main function

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, sigint

I am trying to copy the contents from one file to another, with SIGINT the program gets interrupted to print the number of bytes copied. I tried to use the sigprocmask while the flag initialization, flag check, and flag clear to avoid a race condition. But I don't know how to check whether this sigprocmask works or not. I have been trying to find out quite a long time for this.

```
void signal_handler(int num)
{
    flag = 1;
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    ret = sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);  
     /* Code for 
      * copying the bytes from one file to another
      */
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);         
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("The number of bytes copied are :%llu\n", bytes); 
    flag = 0;
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as you expect. The only thing you need to ensure is that `flag` is of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` to avoid data race on `flag`.

Here's an example. The loop prints the value of `bytes` continuously (it'd wrap around at some point when `bytes` reaches `UINT64_MAX`). You can repeatedly send `SIGINT` to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

void signal_handler(int num)
{
    flag = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t bytes = 0;
    sigset_t set;

    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    int ret = sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);

    while(1) {
        bytes++;
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
        if (flag == 1)
            printf("The number of bytes copied are :%" PRIu64 "\n", bytes);
        flag = 0;
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been posting the question for quite a long time, but I did not get any response. I am a beginner and it was  little difficult to understand the sigprocmask. And the question was only downvoted without one single comment or suggestion. Thanks a lot.